# append elements of differet lists in different excel sheets in R

Tags: r, export

I have a first list like this:

```
[[First]]
    y  sum_1
1 2009 35
2 2010 30
3 2011 20

[[Second]]
    y  sum_1
1 2009  6
2 2010 21
3 2011 40
```

a second list:

```
[[First]]
    y  sum_2
1 2009 20
2 2010 30
3 2011 12

[[Second]]
    y  sum_2
1 2009  9
2 2010 24
3 2011 33
```

and other lists.

I'd like to export each element of a list to a different sheet of the same excel file.
I did this with this code:

```
wb <- createWorkbook()

Map(function(data, nameofsheet){     
  
  addWorksheet(wb, nameofsheet)
  writeData(wb, nameofsheet, data)
  
}, listofdfs, names(listofdfs))

saveWorkbook(wb, file = "C:\\Users\\prova.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

But this works for one list. I don't know how to 'append' the 'First' element of the second list to the 'First' element of the first list in the excel sheet, then the 'Second' and so on.

Thanks!

Comment: No, i'm sorry. I'm just forgetting to do it. I did it for my last question and I'll try to remember for the next ones. Thanks again for reminding me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can bind the list of dataframes into one, then split them based on name and use `write.xlsx`.

```
library(openxlsx)
library(dplyr)

data <- bind_rows(list1, .id = 'id') %>%
           bind_rows(bind_rows(list2, .id = 'id')) %>%
           split(.$id)

write.xlsx(data, file = "data.xlsx")
```

**data**

where `list1`, `list2` in the answer are :

```
list1 <- list(First = structure(list(y = 2009:2011, sum_1 = c(35L, 30L, 
20L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3")), 
Second = structure(list(y = 2009:2011, sum_1 = c(6L, 21L, 40L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3")))

list2 <- list(First = structure(list(y = 2009:2011, sum_2 = c(20L, 30L, 
12L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3")), 
Second = structure(list(y = 2009:2011, sum_2 = c(9L, 24L, 33L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3")))
```

Comment: Thank, it worked! Do you also know how to add one/two empty rows between the appended dataframes in the excel file and add a title for the 'table'?

Comment: No, I am not sure how to include that in the current answer.